# What is date format of EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ssZ?

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, format

I'm trying to parse this on Android:

```
Fri, 02 Oct 2015 10:01:00+0300
```

with this format `EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ssZ`, but doesn't work.

```
item_date = "Fri, 02 Oct 2015 18:07:00+0300";
SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ssZ");

Date dateObj = null;
String newDateStr = item_date;
try {
  dateObj = curFormater.parse(item_date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Space between time and timezone?

Comment: no any spaces, edited

Comment: Then check your locale.

Comment: Added , **Locale.ENGLISH)**; to **SimpleDateFormat **, thanks, works

Comment: Works fine for me. I don't know what Android's implementation of `SimpleDateFormat` is doing.

Answer (score 2):

In order to parse a String into a `Date` which contains certains words (e.g. for the month), then you need an appropriate `Locale` corresponding to the language of these words. Since they are in english in your example you could use a language specific locale like `java.util.Locale.ENGLISH` or a country specific one, like `java.util.Locale.US` or `Locale.UK`.

Since you can pass the `Locale` to the `SimpleDateFormat` constructor your instantiation could look like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

If you like to know the allowed date format words in your currently used `Locale`, then you can try the following snippet, which uses the [`DateFormatSymbols`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html) class:

```
DateFormatSymbols dfs = new DateFormatSymbols();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dfs.getShortMonths()));
```

This class provides corresponding methods to get months, the abbreviated months or the weekdays.
You can also pass a `Locale` to the `DateFormatSymbols` constructor to get these strings from the specific locale.